# How to inject database SYSDATE to a column

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to inject the database (ORACLE) SYSDATE into a column. I want every time an UPDATE occurs, automatically the column "dat_update" receives the database date.

I tried using Hibernate @ColumnTransformer but it isn't working. I'm not sure if this annotation is the best alternative to achieve this.

`

```
@Column(name = "dat_update")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)", write = "?")
private ZonedDateTime lastUpdatedAt;
```

`

Comment: If you can modify the column then you can make ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD dat_update  DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE  ON UPDATE  SYSDATE NOT NULL  ;

Comment: Does it work on Oracle DB? I think ON UPDATE is for MYSQL

Comment: Yes you are right ON UPDATE is mysql, for update you may need to write a trigger or update the column whenever the row is updated.

Comment: Have you tried this annotation `org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp`?

Comment: I tried but this annotation gets the VM date not the database date

Answer (score 1):

As far as Oracle is concerned, a database trigger does the job. Here's an example.

(Setting date format; you don't have to do that, but it'll help us see dates the way we want)

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> create table test
  2    (id         number generated always as identity,
  3     name       varchar2(10),
  4     dat_update date
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  2    before insert or update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.dat_update := sysdate;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID NAME       DAT_UPDATE
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Little     01.12.2022 20:22:03

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> update test set name = 'Yasuda' where name = 'Little';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID NAME       DAT_UPDATE
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Yasuda     01.12.2022 20:22:33
         2 Foot       01.12.2022 20:22:19

SQL>
```